# How to edit path variable in ZSH

Tags: zsh

In my *.bash_profile* I have the following lines:

```
PATHDIRS="
/usr/local/mysql/bin
/usr/local/share/python
/opt/local/bin
/opt/local/sbin
$HOME/bin"
for dir in $PATHDIRS
do
    if [ -d $dir ]; then
        export PATH=$PATH:$dir
    fi
done
```

However I tried copying this to my *.zshrc*, and the `$PATH` is not being set.

First I put `echo` statements inside the "if directory exists" function and I found that the if statement was evaluating to false, even for directories that clearly existed.

Then I removed the directory-exists check, and the `$PATH` was being set incorrectly like this:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:
/usr/local/bin
/opt/local/bin
/opt/local/sbin
/Volumes/Xshare/kburke/bin
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.2-p290/bin
/Users/kevin/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin
/Users/kevin/bin
```

None of the programs in the bottom directories were being found or executed.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Unlike other shells, zsh does not perform word splitting or globbing after variable substitution. Thus `$PATHDIRS` expands to a single string containing exactly the value of the variable, and not to a list of strings containing each separate whitespace-delimited piece of the value.

Using an array is the best way to express this (not only in zsh, but also in ksh and bash).

```
pathdirs=(
    /usr/local/mysql/bin
    …
    ~/bin
)
for dir in $pathdirs; do
    if [ -d $dir ]; then
        path+=$dir
    fi
done
```

Since you probably aren't going to refer to `pathdirs` later, you might as well write it inline:

```
for dir in \
  /usr/local/mysql/bin \
  … \
  ~/bin
; do
  if [[ -d $dir ]]; then path+=$dir; fi
done
```

There's even a shorter way to express this: add all the directories you like to the `path` array, then select the ones that exist.

```
path+=/usr/local/mysql/bin
…
path=($^path(N))
```

The `N` [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) selects only the matches that exist. Add the `-/` to the qualifier list (i.e. `(-/N)` or `(N-/)`) if you're worried that one of the elements may be something other than a directory or a symbolic link to one (e.g. a broken symlink). The `^` [parameter expansion flag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) ensures that the glob qualifier applies to each array element separately.

You can also use the `N` qualifier to add an element only if it exists. Note that you need globbing to happen, so `path+=/usr/local/mysql/bin(N)` wouldn't work.

```
path+=(/usr/local/bin/mysql/bin(N-/))
```

Comment: +1 - Two additional quick tips useful for `$PATH` manipulation in `zsh` (for anyone passing by): *(1)* to prepend instead of append: `path[1,0]=/path/to/dir`, and *(2)* if you're using globbing to find the dirs, you don't have to use a for loop and instead just do `path+=( $PWD/node_modules/**/bin` ) (also works with *(1)* ).

Comment: Thanks, I used your suggestion, with path=($^path(N-/)).
Now is there a way to ensure that same dirs don't duplicate in $PATH each time I run source ~/.zshrc ?
Thanks

Comment: @stansult [Is there a way to add a directory to my PATH in zsh only if it's not already present?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62579/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path-in-zsh-only-if-its-not-already-pre)

Comment: @unthought ***LOVE*** your PRE-pend (`foo[1,0]=bar`) chicanery.  _Gotta love_ the obscurity!

Answer (score 5):

You can put

```
 setopt shwordsplit
```

in your `.zshrc`. Then zsh will perform world splitting like all Bourne shells do. That the default appears to be `noshwordsplit` is a misfeature that causes many a head scratching. I'd be surprised if it wasn't a FAQ. Lets see... yup:
http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq03.html#l18
**3.1: Why does $var where var="foo bar" not do what I expect?**

Answer (score 3):

Still not sure what the problem was (maybe newlines in $PATHDIRS)? but changing to zsh array syntax fixed it:

```
PATHDIRS=(
/usr/local/mysql/bin
/usr/local/share/python
/usr/local/scala/scala-2.8.0.final/bin
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
/opt/local/etc
/opt/local/bin
/opt/local/sbin
$HOME/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin
$HOME/bin)
```

and

```
path=($path $dir)
```